# Ef core code first Error : Key ("Id")=(33) already exists

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-webapi

I am doing a crud for `Destinations` table in a asp.net core project. ( using ef core code first method )

when create a new Destinations I got error in debug console like this.

```
Exception data:
    MessageText: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_Destinations"
    Detail: Key ("Id")=(33) already exists.
    SchemaName: public
    TableName: Destinations
    ConstraintName: PK_Destinations
```

**For some reasons We have already create a Destinations table and added data manually. And now doing a crud for that table**. I guess that's why this error `Key ("Id")=(33) already exists.` occurs.

DbContext.cs

```
public DbSet<Destination> Destinations { get; set; }
```

service.Cs

```
  public async Task<Destination> Create(Destination destination)
        {
            await _catalogDbContext.Destinations.AddAsync(destination);
            await _catalogDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return destination;
        }
```

My Question is

- I have 100 rows in my table. We can not remove them.
  So destination id should start from 301 when adding new destination.
- Our development Database has 200 rows in our table. We can not remove them.
  So destination id should start from 201 when adding new destination.
- Our production Database has 240 rows in our table. We can not remove them.
  So destination id should start from 241 when adding new destination.

How can I do, when create a destination Id should starting from 101, 201 or 241. And The id should increase automatically after a new one is added.?

Edit:
Destination.cs

```
public class Destination
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; private set; }

        [Required]
        public string Continent { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Iso { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please show us how the `Destination` class look like, as well as the `destination` object that you pass to the `Create()` method. :)

Comment: How about letting the database generate the ID. Set the column as identity, tell EF the ID is datavase generated, don't provide ID values when you add entities to the context, when you save them EF will retrieve the Id and update the entity with it so you can use it if you care

Comment: @thesystem @Caius Please check the question. I have edited with `Destination.cs`. The Id is `[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; private set; }`

Comment: Do you have any idea where 33 comes from? Why does it try to create a row with Id 33, of all values? Can we see how you created table via code first? probably done in DbContext with modelbuilder

Comment: Also, you can change Id to a GUID, so you ensure unique value each time.

Comment: @thesystem Id is auto generated (`[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] `). And I have tried 33 times to create a new destination that's why now Id is 33. 
Can we see how you created table via code first? . I added DbContext in my question. please check.
And, I will check with Guid. Thank you

Comment: Your code, in general, looks fine. However, putting `[Key]` and `DatabaseGenerated...` could be redundant, see here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations#key. Quote: "Entity Framework relies on every entity having a key value that is used for entity tracking. One convention of Code First is implicit key properties; Code First will look for a property named “Id”, or a combination of class name and “Id”, such as “BlogId”. This property will map to a primary key column in the database." It handles it automatic. I also dont use DatabaseGenerated, works fine

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new entity, it's better to let `Id` value as default value, don't try to assign it. (For example, Id is `int` so let the value = 0)

```cs
public async Task<Destination> Create()
{
     var destination = new Destination
     {
        Continent = "What ever",
        Country = "...."
        // Init all required properties BUT Id
     };

     // At this line, destination.Id == 0 because you didn't assign a value
     await _catalogDbContext.Destinations.AddAsync(destination);
     await _catalogDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

     // At this line, you should see destination.Id > 0, the value is assigned by EntityFramework
     return destination;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Did you check my question. I also did like that. The problem is I have already create destination table manually. Now I do the crud for destination. Now  Let's say I am going to create  the first new destination Then, destination.Id = 1. Okay? And the error is `Key ("Id")=(1) already exists.`.

Comment: We have two modes of adding data. 1 manually set id, 2 automatic id and you have to choose 1 or 2. In your case. You need both, that is not recommended. You have to write your custom logic so that if an id is already exist then do some things. I think it's easy. Notice that if you have id 1, 2, 3, 4. then you delete 3, so we have the remaining 1, 2, 4 ==> The next auto-id is 5, not 3.

Comment: Okay , Thank you. I will check this way

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with code snippet you have mentioned here. need to work on database side.

what i understood is , your table having pk column id which is identity i.e. auto increment. in such case you need to reseed it. for ex. if your table having existing records then you need to get max value of id column ; let say id column max value is 200. now you have to tell database to set the identity to 200. next time , when new record inserted it will be stored with id=201 and so on.

step to reseed table identity value is as below

`DBCC CHECKIDENT ('yourtablename', RESEED, 200)`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15